# How many repititions of a stochastic algorithm should be done before the results can be considered trustworthy?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have written a stochastic machine learning algorithm.

Each time I run the algorithm on the same test data I get different results. I determine accuracy each time compared to ground truth.

In order to properly assess the system's performance I must run the algorithm on the same test data multiple times and take the mean of the accuracy of all the runs.

**I have been asked to justify the number of runs of the algorithm that I do. Is there a scientific method for determining this or a piece of research I can cite that suggests a value?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value

Comment: I don't see how I can use the p-value in this instance. What would the null hypothesis be in this case?

Answer (score 0):

When assessing accuracy, we assume that your algorithm will generate the correct estimation, and that the mean error hence should be 0. Hence, you should be able to do a p-test with the null hypthesis that the error is 0.

General to look into if you have not already:

- p-hacking
- When you calculate accuracy, you should not validate with your training data, i.e. use true values that are outside of your training interval.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).